# How to convert mixed list with OrderedDict to Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that has mixed OrderedDict as well. I am trying to create a dataframe from that list. I am not sure how I can loop through the list and key value pair in the OrderedDict in the list.

Below is the list:

```
l = [(-2322251069948147489, [OrderedDict([('lat', '46.72161'), ('lon', '-92.45936'), ('name', 'Cloquet'), ('admin1', 'Minnesota'), ('admin2', 'Carlton County'), ('cc', 'US')])]), 
(-2542975094649810558, [OrderedDict([('lat', '38.52491'), ('lon', '-121.9708'), ('name', 'Winters'), ('admin1', 'California'), ('admin2', 'Yolo County'), ('cc', 'US')])]), 
(-1984478776812705270, [OrderedDict([('lat', '38.88101'), ('lon', '-77.10428'), ('name', 'Arlington'), ('admin1', 'Virginia'), ('admin2', 'Arlington County'), ('cc', 'US')])]), 
(-2720329071386930320, [OrderedDict([('lat', '41.70054'), ('lon', '-93.46216'), ('name', 'Bondurant'), ('admin1', 'Iowa'), ('admin2', 'Polk County'), ('cc', 'US')])])]
```

I am trying to transform the above list into a dataframe
What I'm doing is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

This is giving me only 2 columns. What I am trying to get is below

```
           0                 1               2
   -2322251069948147489  Minnesota    Carlton County
   -2542975094649810558  California   Yolo County
   -1984478776812705270  Virginia     Arlington County
   -2720329071386930320  Iowa         Polk County
```

I am not sure how I can look through key -value paid column in dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat` with `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

new_l = [(i[0], i[1][0]) for i in l]
# Unpacks the list of OrderedDict

ind, dicts = map(pd.Series, zip(*new_l))
df = pd.concat([ind, pd.DataFrame(list(dicts))], 1)
```

Output:

```
                     0       lat        lon       name      admin1  \
0 -2322251069948147489  46.72161  -92.45936    Cloquet   Minnesota   
1 -2542975094649810558  38.52491  -121.9708    Winters  California   
2 -1984478776812705270  38.88101  -77.10428  Arlington    Virginia   
3 -2720329071386930320  41.70054  -93.46216  Bondurant        Iowa   

             admin2  cc  
0    Carlton County  US  
1       Yolo County  US  
2  Arlington County  US  
3       Polk County  US
```

You can now select your desired columns : `df[[0, 'admin1', 'admin2']]`:

```
                     0      admin1            admin2
0 -2322251069948147489   Minnesota    Carlton County
1 -2542975094649810558  California       Yolo County
2 -1984478776812705270    Virginia  Arlington County
3 -2720329071386930320        Iowa       Polk County
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

l=[(-2322251069948147489, [OrderedDict([('lat', '46.72161'), ('lon', '-92.45936'), 
('name', 'Cloquet'), ('admin1', 'Minnesota'), ('admin2', 'Carlton County'), ('cc', 
'US')])]), 
(-2542975094649810558, [OrderedDict([('lat', '38.52491'), ('lon', '-121.9708'), 
('name', 'Winters'), ('admin1', 'California'), ('admin2', 'Yolo County'), ('cc', 
'US')])]), 
(-1984478776812705270, [OrderedDict([('lat', '38.88101'), ('lon', '-77.10428'), 
('name', 'Arlington'), ('admin1', 'Virginia'), ('admin2', 'Arlington County'), ('cc', 
'US')])]), 
(-2720329071386930320, [OrderedDict([('lat', '41.70054'), ('lon', '-93.46216'), 
('name', 'Bondurant'), ('admin1', 'Iowa'), ('admin2', 'Polk County'), ('cc', 
'US')])])]

name=[]
admin1=[]
_id= []
for i in l:
    _id.append(i[0])
    name.append(i[1][0]['name'])
    admin1.append(i[1][0]['admin1'])

df= pd.DataFrame(data=[_id,admin1,name]).T
print(df)
```